# Catapult hinge using rigid body constraints

Tags: game-engine, rigid-body-simulation

I'm fairly new to blender, however, I have done a lot of reading, watching youtube videos and searching here before deciding to ask this question.

I am building a simple game that uses a catapult to hurl objects. I've built the catapult but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the hinge on the catapult to work.

I have tried connecting the arm and the hinge bar of the catapult via the Tools -> Physics -> connect (works, but only in blender render, not in blender game), I've tried rigid body constraints (which is where I believe this is supposed to work), I've tried key frames which seemed to work but I couldn't connect the animation to the logic board in Blender Game.

I've attached my blend file if anyone wants to take a look, I would appreciate any help!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxB2pKMjGzzqZjUtSnh1Uks1NDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you upload your file here, other users will be able to better understand your question in the future: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com. Plus it's familiar to the SE site.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting it to work"? What specifically can't you get to work?